# How to add SSL to mailcore

Tags: ios, iphone, imap, mailcore

How Can a configure SSL in mailcore framework. I am using mailcore 1 https://github.com/MailCore/MailCore.

```
    coreAccount = [[CTCoreAccount alloc ] initWithServer:IMAP_SERVER_URL port:IMAP_SERVER_PORT connectionType:CONNECTION_TYPE_TLS authType:IMAP_AUTH_TYPE_PLAIN login:_userName password:_userPwd];
```

Comment: https://github.com/MailCore/MailCore/wiki/Getting-Started appears to show that you need to change the connectionType.

Comment: In fact, it looks like you've done so, so what is the issue? Beware tls and starttls are not the same thing.

Comment: LOGIN informations are visible using sslsplit, i am using authType:IMAP_AUTH_TYPE_PLAIN, is this the problem? what auth type do i need to use?

Comment: Depends on your server. What error are you getting? You haven't provided us any details of what the problem is.